# Can 'NOT' be used in Foreach Generate statement?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there any way that prevents a column not to be generated using Foreach statement in Apache Pig?
Example: `part = FOREACH part GENERATE (NOT $3);` in which a relation called 'part' has columns, say 5. I want all columns to be produced except '$3'. Is there any such way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, create a new relation say part_new and don't include that column in the foreach.

```
part_new = FOREACH part GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$4;
```

Alternatively

```
part_new = FOREACH part GENERATE .. $2,$4;
```